# Flex grow animation does not work when bootstrap 4 style sheet is included

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, transition

I have been trying to get transitions to work with flex grow. It works as expected, but not when I include the bootstrap 4 style sheet. I do not use the bootstrap 4 classes (yet), it is just included.

In the below code when the class "collapsed" is removed from the row, the rows will animated based on flex-grow.

When you edit the snippet and enable the bootstrap style line, it stops working. Can anybody enlighten me why :-)

Here is the js fiddle to see it not working...

[Not working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m8t74rc2/1/)

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".test-row-collapse").removeClass("collapse");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".test-row-collapse").addClass("collapse");
    }, 2000);
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.animate-grow-container {
  flex-basis: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.animate-grow-row {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  transition: all 2s;
  text-align: center;
}

.animate-grow-row-overflow {
  max-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 2s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.collapse .animate-grow-row-overflow {
  max-height: 0;
}

.collapse {
  flex-grow: 0.0001;
}
```

```html
<!-- Enable line below and it stops working :( -->
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animate-grow-container">
  <div class="animate-grow-row" style="background: red">
    <p>This is some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="animate-grow-row" style="background: blue">
    <p>This is some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="animate-grow-row" style="background: green" onclick="$(this).next().removeClass('collapse')">
    <p>This is some content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="animate-grow-row test-row-collapse collapse" style="background: yellow" onclick="$(this).addClass('collapse')">
    <div class="animate-grow-row-overflow">
      <p>This is some content</p>
      <p>This is some content</p>
      <p>This is some content</p>
      <p>This is some content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: the collapse class is also part of bootstrap.